# change amount of numbers in large list and remove empty objects

Tags: r, list, dataframe, export, lapply

I have a large list with 28 object of which some are empty and some are more or less 165 values. 
summary(stim10)

```
      Length Class  Mode   
 [1,] 165    factor numeric
 [2,]   0    factor numeric
 [3,] 165    -none- numeric
 [4,]   0    -none- numeric
 [5,] 166    -none- numeric
 [6,]   0    -none- numeric
 [7,] 166    -none- numeric
```

etc.

Now I want to get these values in a data.frame so I can nicely so analyses on them and export it. 
The way I use to remove an object is

```
stim10[[2]]<-NULL.
```

This must be done from highest to lowest object number since it removes the complete object and changes the order. 
The code I use to make all object the same length to make it ready for data frame is:

```
stim10[[3]]<-stim10[[3]][1:163]
```

Wherein 163 is lowest length of object with values.

Now this works but I would like to have a more elegant way to do this since I will have to apply this to 38 subsets of data. I have tried to use the apply function in a variety of ways, but every way I try it gives the error that I lack a function. In the first line of code I have tried to use assign() but it again returns that I have no function.

I am afraid I just do not get the apply function group well enough to apply it here. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Select non-zero length elements with `stim10[lengths(stim10) != 0]`
then use `lapply` with function `head` to get only first 163 numbers:

```
lapply(stim10[lengths(stim10) != 0], head, 163)
```

Comment: The lapply to head function works perfectly. However when I try to create a new list with this function (or call it separately) it still includes all object with num(0) value

Answer (score 0):

Whereas `stim10[lengths(stim10) != 0]`did not work somehow to select only the object in the list with values. `stim10[lapply(stim10,length)>0]`did do this by selecting all object bigger than 0 (rather than not 0).
Then applying this to the solution by @bergant works:

```
lapply(stim10[lapply(stim10,length)>0], head, 163)
```